# Thunderbird 78: Line breaks are not applied correctly in plain text emails

Tags: thunderbird, plaintext, linebreaks

I have updated Thunderbird to version 78.4 and since then I have a problem to display plain text emails correctly.

I write my e-mails as plain text. Line breaks are created automatically starting at 72 characters. E-mails which I write and send this way are not displayed correctly - at least for me in Thunderbird.

The line breaks are completely removed and only the paragraphs, i.e. double line breaks, are preserved.

Is there a possibility to display the line breaks correctly again? The problem is that Thunderbird now makes my blocks into a one-liner. This looks unattractive and does not comply with the convention to make or display a line break at 72 characters.

**UPDATE:**

Display the e-mail in Thunderbird:

[image: Display the e-mail in Thunderbird]

Source code of the e-mail:

[image]

Volker

Comment: You mean that when you see your own messages in sent they become one liners? What is the value of mail.wrap_long_lines in the config editor?

Comment: Yes, also when I send an e-mail to myself. The value of `mail.wrap_long_lines` is `true` (boolean).